# how to change the connection string when moving Aspnetdb to remote hosting?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection-string

Hi I am abit lost and this is something out of my knowledge.

I was developing a website on development server. I created a user authentication and access rules on my website. So VS created Aspnetdb. I also created a login page using in built login control. I deny all the anonymous users to the page so it will redirect to login page everytime.

Now that I moved aspnetdb and my website to the remote server to the new hosting I bought. I also merged few tables into aspnetdb. But I don't know how to change the connection string for that login control. I didn't write any code myself for that and there is no connection string in the web.config to connect to aspnetdb. For other pages where I created from scratch myself, I changed the connection strings to the aspnetdb and it works fine, but Login control don't.

L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this article and solved the problem. On local machine, the security is embedded into .mdf file i guess. So there is no connection string in webconfig. I guess it was in Asp.net 2 where i can find the change the connection string somewhere. Not sure. But for using only i have to write my own login method (LoginControl.Authenticate) which is pretty straight forward as well. Thanks all. Solved.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1403132.aspx